# Convert rsa to ppk file in MAC

Tags: rsa

I want to convert the id_rsa file to ppk file.  I found there are many websites teaching "how to convert ppk to rsa in MAC" but not vice versa.  Is there a way to convert rsa private key to ppk for windows to use from MAC?

Comment: Do you have `puttygen` installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install PuTTY via homebrew or Mac Ports and specify the output format:

```
puttygen id_rsa -O private -o id_rsa.ppk
```

PuTTY on Windows will load the OpenSSH format key (that you have copied from macOS to Windows), but command line options will [not save it non-interactively](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/puttygen-batch.html). Do so with the menu options: Conversions > Import Key;  File > Save private key.

Comment: Why I'm getting this answer "puttygen: cannot perform this action on a public-key-only input file"?

Comment: This question is about private keys, from which the public key can be derived.  For public, you must provide a private key input, or a public output format. `man puttygen`